# BST Not incrementing Node Count in Java

Tags: java, nodes, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to count the nodes in a BST, however the `retval` is not incrementing. Through debugging I see that each node is being visited, but I'm not sure why it's not incrementing. I know I have 3 nodes in the tree and it returns 0...

```
public int countNodes(){
    if (root == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    return countNodes(root);
}
private int countNodes(LNode ptr){      
    int retval = 1;
    if (root != null && ptr.right == null && ptr.left == null)
        return retval = 1;
    else
        retval = countNodes(ptr.right) + countNodes(ptr.left) + 1;
    return retval;   
}
```

I've also tried not using a `retval` to hold the count:

```
private in countNodes(LNode ptr){
   if (root != null && ptr.right == null && ptr.left == null)
        return 1;
    else
        return= countNodes(ptr.right) + countNodes(ptr.left) + 1;    
}
```

Comment: Please create a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates it returning 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more accurate and relevant:

```
private int countNodes(LNode ptr){      
    if (ptr == null)
        return 0;
    return 1 + countNodes(ptr.left) + countNodes(ptr.right);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! It says I have to wait 8 mins. to mark it though.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax 'return x = y' is incorrect. You mean 'return retval'  or 'return countNodes(ptr.right) + countNodes(ptr.left) + 1;',  as opposed to 'return retval = 1'.

That being said,  orel's answer is the correct way to do this.

Edit: I stand corrected.  Removing  incorrect explanation. But fix the syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure this explains how 0 is being obtained.  In `return retval = 1;`, the `retval = 1` evaluates to `1`, which is what then gets returned.

Comment: The result of the assignment operator is not 0. ["At run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of the variable after the assignment has occurred."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26)